# smarttable requests unnecessary backend calls

Tags: sapui5

sapui5 V: 1.52

## hint:

using smarttable.

I already can sort and filter on client side. no additional requests made to the backend.

## what I want to achive:

- avoid unnecessary database request, when user deselects and selects the column in p13n again.

## steps

1. the user deselects a column (**property2**) in personalisation dialog. (no additional requet to backend, *correct* )
2. the same column (**property2)** is now selected in personalisation dialog. (additional request.. why? )

why does the smarttable request a new database request? The first request had already all properties.

1. GET request from Backend (initial table request):
   Property1,**Property2**,Property3,Property4,Property5,Property6,Property7,Property8
2. GET request from Backend (request done by personalisation Dialog after column selection ):
   Property1,Property3,Property4,Property5,Property6,Property7,Property8,**Property2**

I only deselected Property2 in personalisation manager, clicked ok.
Than I select Property2 again, clicked ok.

Now an unnecessary second Service request is done. why? how do I avoid the unnecessary request?

There are no new columns necessary to retrieve.

## manifest

```js
"settings": {
    "defaultOperationMode": "Client"
    ...
}
```

## xml view

```xml
<smartTable:SmartTable id="SmartTable" entitySet="mySet" tableBindingPath="/mySet" 
    tableType="Table" header="Artikel" showRowCount="true" enableAutoBinding="true" 
    smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" useVariantManagement="false"
    persistencyKey="SmartTableUEreport" useTablePersonalisation="true"
    requestAtLeastFields="Property1,Property2,Property3,Property4,Property5,Property6,Property7,Property8">
```

regards

Comment: This looks like a bug....